# How can I load a list from an mssql table?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
curr = conn.cursor()
sql = """ select order# from Orders WHERE STATUS <> 'Shipped' and STATUS <> 'Not Found' and order# > '' """
curr.execute(sql)
row: List[Any] = curr.fetchall()
for x in row:
    searchInput = x
serchinput_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput")
serchinput_textbox.send_keys(searchInput)
searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_id("searchButton")
searchbutton.click()
```

When I print the row all records are there but in the for loop it is only using the last record.  I'm not sure I have created the list correctly.

Comment: I don't understand why you try to create `searchInput` and don't just juse `row`? And I also don't understand (excuse my ignorance) why you think that `searchInput` should be something different than the last `x` from `row`.

Comment: searchInput is the name of a tag on the website.  I am entering the information from row to call through the searchInput a new page.
     for x in row:
     searchInput = x
    serchinput_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput")
Regardless of what x is looking for, which is a webpage, shouldn't x start with the first element in row when you are using a For loop?  I thought that was  what For loops did, start at the beginning and loop until it reaches the end.

Comment: Yes, it sets the `searchInput` variable to the first `x` in `row`, and then to the second, ..., and then to the last. And **then** it uses that last one to continue with the code and call `driver.find_element_by_id` etc.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still a little confused.  If I do a "print(x)" it prints all of them.  Is there a way to have it process records one at a time and not just process the last one?

Comment: Yes, move the code you wish to be executed for each x *inside* the loop.

Comment: I appreciate your help!!  I realize I hadn't put in a next(x) statement at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop processes your results and does nothing with each row except to assign it to the `searchInput` variable.  You probably want to add  some code *inside the for loop* that will process each row being returned.  Right now, all you'll end up with after your loop is done is `searchInput` containing the last row in your result set.

EDIT:
Try adding the following to see how you're throwing away all rows except the last one:

```
for x in row:
    print("Here's a row to process:", x)  # Add this line
    searchInput = x
```

Comment: I should have added more to the code I posted. I have it pulling information from the website such as ship dates and receive dates. Later I will add this data back to the sql database.  But for now I see it only going to the last record. I have a browser up so I can see what it is doing.

Comment: aa2 = soup.find("div", class_="text-xlarge text-semibold text-primary text-uppercase") print(aa2.text) aa3 = soup.find("div", class_="text-large text-info") print(aa3.text) aa4 = soup.find("div", class_="text-large text-warning") print(aa4.text) aa5 = soup.find("div", class_="text-large text-success") print(aa5.text).                This part of the code under the for loop.  It works on the last record processed.